# Web server benchmark - explanation of results?

Tags: apache-2.4, web-server, docker, benchmark

I made a small benchmark, in which I compare Apache HTTP server deployed to the Virtualbox, and Apache HTTP in Docker (official Alpine and Debian based images) deployed to the Virtualbox. The results of average requests per second are in the following image [Results of the Apache HTTP benchmarking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPdDr.png).

The question is what cause the performance peaks?

For benchmark was used *abc* (GWAN) wrapper with weighttp. Settings of VM were updated according to http://gwan.com/en_apachebench_httperf.html

Benchmark run with [0-500:3000+10x3] => make 3000 request with concurrency from 0 to 500 (with step 10). Every test repeat for 3 times. Configurations of HTTP servers were untouched (default by install). Virtualbox instances were made via Vagrant (Debian Stretch).

I also expect, the default configuration caused that the native Apache HTTP server was slower (with higher concurrency) than the Docker instance. I made the same test for Nginx and results shown same performance stability of docker instance.

BTW, the conclusion of the comparison: performance differences between docker images based on Alpine and Debian are insignificant.

Comment: To explain why you get certain results in a load test you need to also concurrently run (detailed) monitoring on the system you're bench marking. In absence of IO , CPU , memory  stats and detail about the server processes you can't draw any meaningful conclusions about causes (and potential optimalisations )